mysql db configuration in quarkus
Persistence unit '<default>' was configured to run with a database version of at least '8.0.0', but the actual version is '5.5.0'. Consider upgrading your database. Alternatively, rebuild your application with 'quarkus.datasource.db-version=5.5.0' (but this may disable some features and/or impact performance negatively)

I am facing this issue , while connecting to DB --

Well, what version of mysql are you using? Have you tried to [upgrade] your database. Alternatively, rebuild your application with 'quarkus.datasource.db-version=5.5.0.?

is there a docker image ready for this? I need mysql 5.7
So I guess we have to build keycloak server ourself otherwise? Is there an env variable to do this maybe?
